# how to create a loop that create sub lists and add elements to it

Tags: python, list, loops, append

want to create a loop that can create sub lists in a big list and add values from a text file to this list for example i have a text file that contain this data

```
name
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5

name2
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
```

so i created a loop that add the lines from the name till the next empty line and add the read lines as elements to a list,
now i want to create a big list like this `biglist=[name1[],name2[],.....]`
how can i do it using loop to read all the text and create a sub lists with it value in the biglist

```
switches=[["Switch-Edge-4"] ,["Switch-Core-2"],["Switch-Edge-3"],["Switch-Core-2"],["Switch-Core-1"],["Switch-Edge-1"]]
```

def change():

```
SN = e1.get()
NA = e2.get()
switches.append(str(NA))
print(switches)
with fileinput.FileInput("read.txt", inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:


        print(line.replace(str(SN), str(NA)), end='')

   #creat switch

 def creatswitch():
      for i in range (len(switches)):
    te = str(switches[i])

    with open("read.txt", 'r+') as f:
        array = []
        file_data = []

        for line in f:
            if line.startswith(te):
                file_data.append(line.split("#")[0])

                for line in f:  
     lines to keep
                    if not line.rstrip():
                        break  
      for switch
                    file_data.append(line.split("#")[0])
                    "".join(file_data)

        print(file_data)

        array = []

        for i in range(1, 37):
            try:
                if (int("".join(file_data[i][:2])) in range(1, 37)):
                    array.append(file_data[i])
                else:
                    array.append("  not")


            except:
                array.append("  None")
        print("befor slice", array)
        print(len(array))
```

Comment: can you please post some sample output.

Comment: What code have you written for this?

Comment: first of all thanks for the editing

Comment: You need to format your code properly.